# Adding an hour to datetime in Julia?

Tags: datetime, julia, date-arithmetic

Say I have a datetime and I want to add an arbitrary time period to that datetime and get a new datetime. For example, I want to find the date and time after 333 hours after new year's eve.

Two issues arise:

1. I can't actually create an Time more than 23hours
2. If I do create a ::Time, I can't add it to a ::DateTime

My question basically is how do you do add Times together?

**Code**

```
julia> dt = DateTime(2021,1)
2021-01-01T00:00:00

julia> t = Time(333)
ERROR: ArgumentError: Hour: 333 out of range (0:23)

julia> t = Time(1)
01:00:00

julia> dt + t
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching +(::DateTime, ::Time)
Closest candidates are:
  +(::Any, ::Any, ::Any, ::Any...) at operators.jl:560
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You shouldn't be adding `Time`s together, as these are instances in time. You want to be adding `Period`s to your `Time` to figure out what time it is after the period has elapsed:

```
julia> using Dates

julia> dt = DateTime(2021,1)
2021-01-01T00:00:00

julia> dt + Hour(333)
2021-01-14T21:00:00

julia> Hour <: Period
true

julia> Time <: Period
false
```